# JFugue MusicString key setting not working

Tags: java, jfugue

I am new to JFugue, and I've been trying some stuff, but i can't change the key of a MusicString. Here's what I try:

```
Player player = new Player();
player.play("KBmaj T120 C D E F G A B");
```

It just doesn't change the key.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using JFugue version 5.0+ but following directions for JFugue version 4.x. In the latest version of JFugue, the key is set like this: "KEY:Bmaj"

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Didn't know I was following an outdated guide. Do you know any guide to the newest versions of JFugue? I'm using [this](http://www.jfugue.org/4/jfbmrkklprpp/TheCompleteGuideToJFugue-v1.pdf) one, but it seems to be a little old.